# Convert markdown backticks to asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I'm switching over from markdown to asciidoc and have a question. In my markdown file, I use backticks to indicate code font (`foo.bar()`). When this is converted to html, the text gets placed inside code blocks (`foo.bar()`).

How should I format a text fragment in asciidoc if I want it to appear within code blocks when the document is converted to html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late and short answer:

You can use backticks just like in Markdown.

From the [AsciiDoc User manual](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html):

> **Monospaced text**
>
> Word phrases +enclosed in plus characters+ are rendered in a monospaced font. Word phrases  `enclosed in backtick characters` (grave accents) are also rendered in a monospaced font but in this case the enclosed text is rendered literally and is not subject to further expansion

Comment: Note that from asciidoctor (not asciidoc!) 1.5 onwards, the syntax changed slightly (http://asciidoctor.org/news/2014/08/12/asciidoctor-1-5-0-released/). The content of backticks now *is* subject to further expansion. The plus signs no longer yield monospaced font, they just prevent expansion. To get both, you need to nest plus signs in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://powerman.name/doc/asciidoc), you can use `foo.bar()` the same way in asciidoc.

[Here's an example of that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edusantana/linguagem-de-programacao-i-livro/master/livro/capitulos/cap5-arquivos.adoc):

```
    * Utilizar as funções `fgetc` ou `getc` para ler carácteres (...);
```